# Assignment showing incorrect results, but my code seems to output the correct results

Tags: python, arrays

The code should allow the user to input 8 batting averages, and then display the minimum, maximum, and average batting averages. In assignment, the commented code is included and telling me what to put, and where.

I thought I had it correct, and it results in what I believe to be the exact same results as the assignment expects, but it still shows that I am failing both checks.

```
# Declare a named constant for array size here.
MAX_AVERAGES = 8

# Declare array here.
averages = []
# Write a loop to get batting averages from user and assign to array.
for x in range(MAX_AVERAGES):
    averageString = input("Enter a batting average: ")
    battingAverage = float(averageString)
    # Assign value to
    averages.append(battingAverage)
# Assign the first element in the array to be the minimum and the maximum.
minAverage = averages[0]
maxAverage = averages[0]
# Start out your total with the value of the first element in the array.
total = averages[0]
# Write a loop here to access array values starting with averages[1]
for x in range(1, MAX_AVERAGES):
    # Within the loop test for minimum and maximum batting averages.
    if averages[x] < minAverage:
        minAverage = averages[x]
    if averages[x] > maxAverage:
        maxAverage = averages[x]



    # Also accumulate a total of all batting averages.
    total += averages[x]

# Calculate the average of the 8 batting averages.
average = total / MAX_AVERAGES

# Print the batting averages stored in the averages array.
print(averages)

# Print the maximum batting average, minimum batting average, and average batting average.
print("Maximum batting average: ", maxAverage)
print("Minimum batting average: ", minAverage)
print("Average batting average: ", average)
```

I've rewritten this code multiple times, resulting in the same exact results every time. When I select to complete the checks, it shows that both tests are failing. I have written it in PyCharm and copied over, written multiple times directly in the assignments code editor, and nothing.

[image: Result for test 1]

[Result for test 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNEgj.png)

I know there probably is some simple solution im missing, but I just can't seem to figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: Looks like the result evaluator is being picky, possibly doesn't expect you to print averages before the 3 statements

Comment: I wonder if you added this `# Print the batting averages stored in the averages array.
print(averages)` later on to debug? If it was there prior, try to remove it

Comment: Should you be printing the minimum before the maximum like in the `Expected Output`?

Comment: You're printing two spaces between each of the labels and its numeric value - one as part of the label, and one that `print()` adds as a separator between items.  Perhaps the checker is sufficiently picky to object to those extra spaces?

Comment: The code you show doesn't match the supposed Results output (note "is" vs ":") . Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see if it is only the comparator on that site being picky:

```py
print(f"Minimum batting average is {minAverage}")
print(f"Maximum batting average is {maxAverage}")
print(f"Average batting average is {average}")
```

also, remove the print above

```py
print(averages)
```